# create element with js and add transition

Tags: javascript

I am creating an html element with js with a width of 0
I would like to transit it to a different width

this will show the transition (obviously unusable)

```
element.style.transition = "all 0.4s ease";
element.style.width = 0;
alert(123);
element.style.width = 100;
```

this will also work

```
element.style.width = 0;
setTimeout(open, 1, element); //having the width=100 in the function
```

this will NOT work

```
element.style.width = 0;
element.style.width = 100;
```

what i would like to know if there is some event i can listen to
on whose trigger i can apply the new size and the transition is visible

the settimeout is basically doing what i want but i would prefer to now if there is an event or a different way to do this

P.S not interested in Jquery or any kind of extension

EDIT -->

here some more code

```
x: function(){
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", y);

},
y: function(){
  t = document.getElementById("body");  
  d = document.createElement('div');
  d.style.height = 100;
  d.style.width = 100;
  d.style.background ="#f00"
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);;
  d.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);;
  d.style.transition = "all 5s ease";
  t.appendChild(d);
  setTimeout(z, 100, d);

},
z: function(d){
  d.style.background ="#00f";  
}
```

setting the timeout to 100 seams to work setting it to 10 and it misses some setting it to 1 and it misses nearly every 
so my conclusion if i set the timer to 1 it applys the new color before "something" has happened and there is no transition but its streit blue
so i am looking for this "something"
like addeventlistener("objectcreatedandcanbetransitioned")
so how to do the above whit OUT settimer and whit out some cheat by creating an object and start the transition when i create the next

Comment: What do you want? To start the transition if some button is clicked for example?

Answer (score 1):

The list of events are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

In the following code I set the width to zero. Then I have a function that changes the width. I set an event listener on `myBtn` for the `click` event, but it can be any event from the list above. The second parameter is the function to call when the event happens which is the `callbackFunc()` which is where I change the width to 100.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="element">My Header</div>

<p>Click the button to see the width change.</p>

<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>



<script>

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", callbackFunc);

var element = document.getElementById("element")
element.style.width = "0px";
element.style.overflow = "hidden";

function callbackFunc() {
   
   element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
   element.style.width = "100px";
element.style.transition = "all 2s";


element.style.width = "100px";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also you probably need to have overflow hidden

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you want to wait until the DOM content is loaded, here is [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/3294482) on how to handle document ready without jQuery. This means that you start the transition after the DOM loads (with 0px width) and sets it to 100px with right away.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("element");
element.style.transition = "all 0.4s ease"
element.style.width = "0px";
var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
var toggleFunc = function() {
  if (element.style.width === "0px") {
    element.style.width = "100px";
  } else {
    element.style.width = "0px";
  }
};
toggle.addEventListener("click", toggleFunc);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', toggleFunc, false);
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">
  Toggle
</button>
<div id="element" class="box" />
```